Problema entre SharedTransitionLayout y MotionLayout en Jetpack Compose
Actualmente mi aplicación utiliza SharedTransitionLayout para hacer una animación desde el título de la SplashScreen y la barra superior de mi aplicación que también incluye este título.
Esto funciona perfectamente, excepto que descubrí un problema cuando intenté usar MotionLayout para hacer una barra de herramientas colapsable con Jetpack Compose.
Si MotionLayout está dentro de SharedTransitionLayout, no se muestra, pero si elimino la envoltura de SharedTransitionLayout, se muestra, ¿es un bug conocido?
@OptIn(ExperimentalSharedTransitionApi::class)
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            MotionEventExampleTheme {

                SharedTransitionLayout {

                    Column {

                        var progress by remember {
                            mutableFloatStateOf(0f)
                        }

                        ProfileHeader(
                            progress = progress
                        )

                        Spacer(
                            modifier = Modifier.height(32.dp)
                        )

                        Slider(
                            value = progress,
                            onValueChange = {
                                progress = it
                            },
                            modifier = Modifier.padding(
                                horizontal = 32.dp
                            )
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMotionApi::class)
@Composable
fun ProfileHeader(progress: Float) {

    val context = LocalContext.current

    val motionScene = remember {
        context.resources
            .openRawResource(R.raw.motion_scene)
            .readBytes()
            .decodeToString()
    }

    MotionLayout(
        motionScene = MotionScene(content = motionScene),
        progress = progress,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        val properties = motionProperties(id = "recipe_image")
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(Color.DarkGray)
                .layoutId("box")
        )
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.picture),
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier
                .clip(CircleShape)
                .border(
                    width = 2.dp,
                    color = properties.value.color("background"),
                    shape = CircleShape
                )
                .layoutId("recipe_image")
        )
        Text(
            text = "Philipp Lackner",
            fontSize = 24.sp,
            modifier = Modifier.layoutId("recipe_title"),
            color = properties.value.color("background")
        )
    }
}

Vídeo de ejemplo de lo que ocurre:
https://imgur.com/a/nGjI3KZ

Veo el video que muestras y es muy raro el problema que presentas, posiblemente es un bug usando SharedTransitionLayout y MotionLayout, pero no encontré algún registro de este problema.

Para quien pueda servirle, abrí una issues en Google y era un problema de ellos que está solucionado en la versión 1.1.0-alpha14 de la librería de constraint:
androidx-constraint = { group = "androidx.constraintlayout", name = "constraintlayout-compose", version.ref = "constraint" }

